# Get string from array scanned directory

Tags: php, arrays, regex, sorting, dirname

I have this array which is the result of a directory scan on my external drive where I have stored my e-books collection:

```
Array
(
    [Asa Larsson] => Array
        (
            [De tweede zonde (12786)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => De tweede zonde - Asa Larsson.epub
                    [1] => metadata.opf
                    [2] => cover.jpg
                )

            [Zonnestorm (6275)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Zonnestorm - Asa Larsson.epub
                    [1] => metadata.opf
                    [2] => cover.jpg
                )

            [Het zwarte pad (6296)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Het zwarte pad - Asa Larsson.epub
                    [1] => metadata.opf
                    [2] => cover.jpg
                )

            [Midzomernacht (6281)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => metadata.opf
                    [1] => cover.jpg
                    [2] => Midzomernacht - Asa Larsson.epub
                )

            [Tot de woede is geluwd (6274)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Tot de woede is geluwd - Asa Larsson.epub
                    [1] => metadata.opf
                    [2] => cover.jpg
                )

        )

    [Asa Harrison] => Array
        (
            [Dodelijke stilte (15028)] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Dodelijke stilte - Asa Harrison.epub
                    [1] => metadata.opf
                    [2] => cover.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

In every array there is a different amount of books.
Also note that the .epub file is not always on the same index.
Considering the first array (4 e-books) I would like to end up with the following strings:

```
$dir_1 = Asa Larsson/De tweede zonde (12786)/De tweede zonde - Asa Larsson.epub
$dir_2 = Asa Larsson/Zonnestorm (6275)/Zonnestorm - Asa Larsson.epub
$dir_3 = Asa Larsson/Het zwarte pad (6296)/Het zwarte pad - Asa Larsson.epub
$dir_4 = Asa Larsson/Midzomernacht (6281)/Midzomernacht - Asa Larsson.epub
$dir_4 = Asa Larsson/Tot de woede is geluwd (6274)/Tot de woede is geluwd - Asa Larsson.epub

$dir_6 = Asa Harrison/Dodelijke stilte (15028)/Dodelijke stilte - Asa Harrison.epub
```

**EDIT**

**Rightly I have got some criticism about the fact that I didn't post any code and the reason for this is that this excerpt is a small part of a very old php 4 project which I have made when I was still young in my spare time in order to manage my collection. I am now a 77 years old man just trying to get some help and was not my intention to hurt nobody feelings or proud.
I apologize for this.**

I have no problems getting the epub files I will filter the array looking for the one with the .epub extension, I have been struggling getting the First and second directory names.

I can not figure out how to achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you attempted this problem for yourself at all? You have not shown any code to support that if that is the case

Comment: How do you build this array? Why same data are not at same index?

Comment: @Toto, I get the e-book files from several friends and this is the way I have got it. Because it goes over about a few thousand files I really can not check them one for one. The array comes from a scandir() request over the e-book folder in which the files are stored in.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, This comes from a scandir() over a folder which contains the files. I have tried several approaches attempting to read and extract the directory names. I have also searched for solution in here but this is a little different from all the answers. I am really not use to post here question expecting everyone work for my problems. I was used to be a developer my self, but I quit several year ago. The really big problem is that I am 77 year old and I forget very often things. This issue here is too big for me.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://3v4l.org/hXCvR) helps you towards a solution.

Comment: Hi @berend, thank you very much to point me out. I can now see and remember why I couldn't come out. I did three foreach() loops one after an other. I see that you first store some data before the third loop and then you collect the rest after it. I appreciated.